# Software for tracking submissions to stock video/photo agencies?

Tags: video, photography, workflow, digital-asset-management

I am looking for software that can track which media files I have uploaded to various stock media agencies.  I work primarily with digital video but I also do some still stock photography as well.  Ideally said software would include fields for keywords, contracts (exclusive/non-exclusive), date of upload for each agency.  It would be terrific if it were FOSS and ran cross-platform (though I can run it on any of the three main operating systems).

If such an application doesn't exist standalone, is there perhaps a website (yes I already know about Blackbox.global, but that is only for four of the stock agencies, I want to track many more than that).

Some more details (thanks to Nicolas Raoul for helping me surface these):

- Information I upload to each agency (image/video, title, keywords, editorial toggle, editorial description, model/property release), would remain en toto on my computer.
- Nice to have: Tracking upload dates for each piece of media to each agency.
- I would prefer this to be a self-contained gallery viewer. If only Adobe Lightroom and DaVinci Resolve had plugins or add-ons that would do exactly this.

Thank in advance for your expertise!